# ioHook no inicia ni retrona ningun error (node)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, eventos

El problema es que estoy utilizando `ioHook` para capturar los eventos del teclado fuera de mi aplicación en node y no puedo hacerlo arrancar.

Realmente no me da ningún error en consola, esto es lo único que se imprime:

```javascript
refresh_locale_list [476]: GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, NULL) found 3 layouts.
refresh_locale_list [493]: Received 3 locales.
load_input_helper [866]: refresh_locale_list() found 3 locale(s).
```

Y este es la mínima expresión de mi index.js en la que no puedo resolver el problema (básicamente desde que se importa):

```javascript
import ioHook from 'ioHook'

iohook.on('keydown', key => {
  console.log(code)
})
```

Estoy utilizando `esm` para correr mi código y antes estaba bundleando con rollup y babeljs pero no fueron las causas del problema, aun así, intentando con cjs `require` igual nada pasa.

Estoy utilizando node 15.4.0 pero intenté con node 10.9.0 (con nvm) haciendo el reinstall de ioHook y nada, la instalación es tal cual indica en la [documentación](https://wilix-team.github.io/iohook/installation.html) y no lo he integrado a electron, así que básicamente solo se está ejecutando en node.

Muchas gracias de antemano.